# Receiving NaN from an anonymous function in matlab

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, nan, piecewise

I'd like to implement a piecewise periodic function, which should be zero in certain intervals and look like a test function elsewhere (e.g. `exp(a^2/(abs(x)^2-a^2))` for `abs(x)< a` and zero otherwise).
I tried

```
nu = @(x) ((8*10^(-4)/exp(1)*exp(30^2./(abs(mod(x,365)-31).^2-30.^2))).* ... 
        and((1<mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<61)) + ...
      (8*10^(-4)/exp(1)*exp(10^2./(abs(mod(x,365)-300).^2-10.^2))).* ...
        and((290<mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<310)));
```

respectively

```
nu = @(x) ((0*x).* and((0<=mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<=1)) + ...
      (8*10^(-4)/exp(1)*exp(30^2./(abs(mod(x,365)-31).^2-30.^2))).* ... 
        and((1<mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<61)) + ...
      (0*x).* and((61<=mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<=290)) + ...
      (8*10^(-4)/exp(1)*exp(10^2./(abs(mod(x,365)-300).^2-10.^2))).* ...
        and((290<mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<310)) + ...
      (0*x).* and((310<=mod(x,365)),(mod(x,365)<365)));
```

which should behave the same. The aim is to have a period of [0,365), therefore the modulo.

Now my problem is that `nu(1)=nu(61)=nu(290)=nu(310)=NaN` and also in a small neighborhood of them, e.g. `nu(0.99)=NaN`. But I excluded these points from the exponential function, where this one would cause problems. And even if I use a smaller interval for the exponential functions (e.g (2,60) and (291,309)) I receive `NaN` at the same points.

Any ideas? Thanks in advice!

Comment: evaluate that function piece by piece for those values, and you'll see where that NaN is coming from ;) btw: `0*NaN+1 = NaN`

Answer (score 0):

One trick I use when performing vectorised calculations in which there's risk of a division by zero or related error is to use the conditional to modify the problem value. For instance, suppose you wanted to invert all entries in a vector, but leave zero at zero (and set any value within, say, 1e-8 to zero, too). You'd do this:

```
outVect = 1./(inVect+(abs(inVect)<=1e-8)).*(abs(inVect)>1e-8);
```

For values satisfying the condition that abs(value)>1e-8, this calculates 1/value. If abs(value)<=1e-8, it actually calculates 1/(value+1), then multiplies by zero, resulting in a zero value. Without the conditional inside the denominator, it would calculate 1/value when value is zero, resulting in inf... and then multiply inf by zero, resulting in NaN.

The same technique should work with your more complicated anonymous function.